# Kendo Template onClick in element does not work

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="logotemplate">
    <div >
        <h3>#: name#</h3>
         # for (var i=0; i< options.length;i++) { #
             <img src="#= options[i].url #" class="item-photologos" onclick="clickedImage(name,i)"   />
         # } #
    </div>
</script>
```

I have a custom Kendo Mobile Listview template. The images show up as expected, but the onclick doesnot fire and no errors are seen in the logs.  I have tried many different combinations of #: #, ##, #= #, etc around the onclick method, but doesnot work (in some of these cases, i see error messages like "i is not defined").  Help will be appreciated.

Comment: where is the ""i is not defined" thrown from? After this runs and images displayed can you "view source" and see the calls are set-up accurately?

Comment: Its thrown from the 1st line from my main html file, there is nothing there. So cant tell much from that. In the sources, I dont see anything wrong: it shows onclick="clickedImage(name,i)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="logotemplate">
<div >
    <h3>Blah</h3>
    # for (var i=0; i< options.length;i++) { #
    <img src="#= options[i].url#" class="item-photologos" onclick="clickedImage('#: options[i].name #' , #:i #)"   />
    # } #
</div>
```

Where the parameters inside `clickedImage` are passed in and not hard-coded strings.

This renders the following:

```
   <div>
    <h3>Blah</h3>
    <img src="foo.jpg" class="item-photologos" onclick="clickedImage('Jane Doe' , 0)"   />
    <img src="bar.jpg" class="item-photologos" onclick="clickedImage('John Doe' , 1)"   />
  </div>
```

As opposed to

```
<div >
    <h3>Blah</h3>
    <img src="foo.jpg" class="item-photologos" onclick="clickedImage(name,i)"   />
    <img src="bar.jpg" class="item-photologos" onclick="clickedImage(name,i)"   />
</div>
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hLzfx2zm/)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need, and I see that your jsfiddle works. Unfortunately, when I do the same thing, the click even does not fire and I see no error. Maybe I am doing something else wrong, I will try to get as close to your solution as possible.

Comment: I closed the tab and opened my html in another and now this works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery On method on each image to add click event listener.

```js
$(".item-photologos").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not what i need...this will fire when the entire row is clicked, I want individual images to be clickable